# Flutter build appbundle failed

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build my flutter appbundle but I got an error saying:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file '/Users/user/key.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.
```

Here is my release in build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your keystore file path is not valid and as I don't know where you put your key.jks file then you may follow these steps.

1. Move/paste your key.jks file inside your project's `{project-root}/android/app/`
2. Create keystore properties file `key.properties` in your project's `{project-root}/android` module and use this code and replace `****` with your value/keys

   ```
   storePassword=****
   keyPassword=*****
   keyAlias=****
   storeFile=./key.jks
   ```
3. Open `{project-root}/android/app/build.gradle` and paste this code inside `signingConfigs`

   ```
   release {
       keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
       storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
   ```
4. Add this block before `android` section in `app/build.gradle`

   ```
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

here is the documentation how you implement

> https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android